# Dynamic amount of '.parent'

Tags: actionscript-3, loops, parent-child

I have 2 object. In different depths of MovieClip. I would like to know if object A parent is same with object B parent. I wanted to dynamically add '.parent' to object A/B till it both reaches the same level (having the same parent object). How can I do that?

My idea was to have something like

```
objectA = objectA + ".parent"
```

and make it loop till it reaches the target. But this is not the correct way to add in more layers of '.parent'. Anyone know how it should be coded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [contains](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/display/DisplayObjectContainer.html#contains%28%29) method

> `public function contains(child:DisplayObject):Boolean`
>   Determines whether the specified display object is a child of the `DisplayObjectContainer` instance or the instance itself. The search includes the entire display list including this `DisplayObjectContainer` instance, grandchildren, great-grandchildren, and so on.

```
function haveCommonParent(a:DisplayObject, b:DisplayObject):Boolean
{
  for(var p:DisplayObjectContainer = a.parent; p != null; p = p.parent)
  {
      if(p.contains(b))
          return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

Might be slow for huge display lists.

Update: get the common parent, if any. This will return a `Stage` object if both are on stage.

```
function getCommonParent(a:DisplayObject, b:DisplayObject):DisplayObjectContainer
{
  for(var p:DisplayObjectContainer = a.parent; p != null; p = p.parent)
  {
      if(p.contains(b))
          return p;
  }
  return null;
}
```

Comment: May be better to return the common parent, or `null` if there is none.  As it is, this will return `true` most of the time, as all objects in a scene typically share the stage as a common ancestor.

Answer (score 0):

```
var mc:MovieClip;
while (mc.parent != null && mc.parent != targetParent)
{
    mc = mc.parent;
}
```

Comment: Using `DisplayObjectContainer` instead of `MovieClip` would be a better choice, if not the loop may fail.